# How to process webservice json data in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

My webservice serves me the following json.

```
{"data":{"error":null,"success":true,"id":"129","userId":"dasfasf@afdsfgd.com","password":"pass123","email":"dasfasf@afdsfgd.com","name":"aasdasd","type":"candidate","img":"http:\/\/www.mo.bluehorse.in\/proximity\/admin\/images\/candidate\/defaultimg.png","industry":"Accounting \/ Finance","functionnml":"Architects \/ Interior Design \/ Naval Arch.","role":"Architect","summary":"VDFSVGDS","linkedin_id":"FSDAFSDAFDS"}}
```

And i am trying to access this via

```
NSArray *logedInUser = [NSArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray *)[jsonData valueForKey:@"data"]];
```

I have also tried

```
NSMutableArray *logedInUser = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray *)[jsonData valueForKey:@"data"]];
```

I am new is iOS. Please help me to get data from the above json.

And after receiving the data i want to save it to `NSUserDefaults *preferences`
So my code is as follows

```
NSUserDefaults *preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            NSString *currentLevelKey = @"logedInUser";
[preferences setObject:logedInUser forKey:currentLevelKey];
const BOOL didSave = [preferences synchronize];
if(didSave){//my own code is here}
```

It gives me the following error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSArray
>   initWithArray:range:copyItems:]: array argument is not an NSArray' ***

Also please let me know is this ok or i need to do something else.

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Show more relevant code. How was `jsonData` created? And what problem are you actually having with the posted code?

Comment: as I see your [jsonData valueForKey:@"data"] isn't NSArray. try parse it to NSDictionary

Comment: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/basic-json-parsing-in-ios/ learn from here.

Comment: It gives me the following error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSArray initWithArray:range:copyItems:]: array argument is not an NSArray'
***

Comment: please read the error message

Comment: You haven't got the foggiest idea what you're doing, do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *string = @"{\"data\": {\"error\": null,\"success\": true,\"id\": \"129\",\"userId\": \"dasfasf@afdsfgd.com\",\"password\": \"pass123\",\"email\": \"dasfasf@afdsfgd.com\",\"name\": \"aasdasd\",\"type\": \"candidate\",\"img\": \"http://www.mo.bluehorse.in/proximity/admin/images/candidate/defaultimg.png\",\"industry\": \"Accounting / Finance\",\"functionnml\": \"Architects / Interior Design / Naval Arch.\",\"role\": \"Architect\",\"summary\": \"VDFSVGDS\",\"linkedin_id\": \"FSDAFSDAFDS\"}}";

        NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:NULL];
        NSLog(@"dict : %@",dict);
        NSMutableArray *allvalues = [NSMutableArray array];
        [allvalues addObjectsFromArray:[dict objectForKey:@""]];
        NSUserDefaults *preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        for (NSDictionary *value in [dict objectForKey:@"data"]) {
            NSLog(@"value : %@:%@",value,[[dict objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:value]);
            [preferences setValue:value forKey:[[dict objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:value]];
        }
```

Comment: Thank You rahul. u just saved me. thanx a lot

Answer (score 0):

You getting jsonData in the form of NSDictionary not NSArray...Try below code

```
NSDictionary *dictData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

NSDictionary *dataDict=[dictData objectForKey:@"data"];

NSUserDefaults *preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *currentLevelKey = @"logedInUser";
[preferences setObject:dataDict forKey:currentLevelKey];
const BOOL didSave = [preferences synchronize];
if(didSave){//my own code is here}

//(OR) If your dictionary contains data other than NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. so you need to store like below

NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.selectedOptionPositions];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"logedInUser"];

//Retrieving:

NSData *dictionaryData = [preferences objectForKey:@"logedInUser"];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dictionaryData];
```

Hope it useful to you...!